# Javascript/Dom loading images in to grid

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm pretty new to programming and javascript/dom. Ultimately, I'm trying to make a sliding puzzle game but to start off with, I'm just trying to get the images loading up in a random order. It's going to be a 4x4 grid of images. The images are named Tree00, 01, 02, 03, 10, etc up to 33. Here's my code so far:

```
        <html>
<head>
<title>Shuffle</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
Pics = new Array();
var Top = 16;

for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
  document.write("<img><img><img><img><br>");
}

function RandomInt(Min, Max) {
  RI = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
  return(RI);
}

function Shuffle() {
  N = RandomInt(0, 1);
  this.Image.src=Pics[N];
  this.Image.style.left = 220;


}

function ViewerObj(Image, Pics, i) {
  this.Image = Image;
  this.Image.style.left = 800;
  this.Pics = Pics;
  this.Shuffle = Shuffle;
  this.Image.id = "ID" + i;
}

function Randomise() {
  var i;

  for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
    Viewers[i].Shuffle();
    Viewers[i].Image.style.left = 200;
  }
}

Viewers = new Array();
var i;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Pics[i] = "images/Tree" + (i) + (i + 1) + ".jpg";  
}

for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
  document.images[i].src = "images/Blank.jpg";
  document.images[i].style.left = 300;
  Viewers[i] = new ViewerObj(document.images[i], Pics, i);
}


//-->
</script>
<h1>Shuffle</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Shuffle" onClick="Randomise();"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just can't quite fathom what I need to be changing and how I'd go about it. Any help + explanation would be much appreciated. What I am trying to achieve is it loading every image but just in a random order, but with no duplicates.

Comment: You didn't describe what problem you are having. Just that "something" needs to change. Please ask an actual question.

Comment: I've edited it, my bad! Basically I want it to be loading every image not just one or two which is what is happening now. Any guidance on how to make this not repeat images is much appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few problems in your script :

first replace

```
for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
  document.write("<img><img><img><img><br>");
}
```

by

```
for(i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
 document.write("<img>");
 if ((i+1)%4 == 0) {
  document.write("<br>");
 }
}
```

you will get only 16 IMG elements instead of 4*16 in your code

then you will need 16 different names for your images : replace

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 Pics[i] = "images/Tree" + (i) + (i + 1) + ".jpg";  
}
```

by

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
 Pics[j+4*i] = "images/Tree" + (i) + (j) + ".jpg";  
}
}
```

Then you biggest problem is the shuffling. You cannot shuffle the "Viewers" one-by-one because you want to avoid duplicates. Each viewer must randomly select a unique image.

For this you can use the technique in mdarwi's answer : shuffle the Pics table for instance.

check your modified code on jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/oreje4/edit)

Comment: Thank you so much, that has absolutely sorted my problem. Do you have any tips on what my next steps should be to add an onClick method that switches images? I've basically made the last image (33) as the blank image so if an image tat is next to this one is clicked then it should displace it.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is simply that you'd like the images to be properly shuffled, you can use the following code (taken directly from the Javascript sample code for the [Fisher-Yates shuffle on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
var n = a.length;
for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

The easiest thing to do would be to rename your images Tree1 to TreeN, and then place N integers in an array and shuffle them using the above algorithm.

Comment: Would renaming the images make it harder to achieve my ultimate goal of making a sliding puzzle game? also, when something is in an array I assume it is given a position number? so this position number could ultimately be used in an onclick method for swapping images around?

Answer (score 0):

***(This is a code-comment, not an answer)***

---

```
Pics = new Array();
```

The `Pics` variable should be declared before using. Also, use the shorthand notation `[]`

```
var Pics = [];
```

---

```
var Top = 16;

for (i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
    document.write("<img><img><img><img><br>");
}
```

The `i` variable is declared only later in the code. It should be declared at the top of the program.

---

```
function RandomInt(Min, Max) {
    RI = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
    return (RI);
}
```

This is particularly dangerous: the `RI` variable is not declared inside the function, so it becomes an implicit global property. That should be avoided. Also, the parens in the return statement are superfluous.

```
function RandomInt(Min, Max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
}
```

---

```
function Shuffle() {
    N = RandomInt(0, 1);
    this.Image.src = Pics[N];
    this.Image.style.left = 220;    
}
```

Again, the `N` variable should be declared. Also, why is this "method" declared outside of the `ViewerObj` constructor? Either, put it inside, or - even better - add it to the constructors prototype object. That way, there will only be one `Shuffle` function object instead of many.

---

```
function ViewerObj(Image, Pics, i) {
    this.Image = Image;
    this.Image.style.left = 800;
    this.Pics = Pics;
    this.Shuffle = Shuffle;
    this.Image.id = "ID" + i;
}

function Randomise() {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
        Viewers[i].Shuffle();
        Viewers[i].Image.style.left = 200;
    }
}

Viewers = new Array();
var i;
```

As mentioned above, the `i` variable should be declared on top. Also, the `Viewers` variable should be declared.

```
var Viewers = [];
```

---

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Pics[i] = "images/Tree" + (i) + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
}

for (i = 0; i < Top; i++) {
    document.images[i].src = "images/Blank.jpg";
    document.images[i].style.left = 300;
    Viewers[i] = new ViewerObj(document.images[i], Pics, i);
}
```